# Android slide objects while it is follow my finger

Tags: android, android-sliding

I know how slide objects right and left but I want the object follow my finger.
How I can do this?

Comment: LinearLayout .. There are some TextViews and not changing other objects, only the texts are replaced after the slide

Comment: Use this tutorial : http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2010/06/making-sense-of-multitouch.html

Comment: I do not understand this guide. Could you please bring me the code?

Comment: guide provides to you required information.